# Compose characters

Tags: text-editing, unicode, character-composition

I have some copied text from a pdf which renders like this with my current font:

[image]

I know I could use a different font that handles Unicode characters better, but I would rather find a function to compose the two characters into one character:

```
a" --> ä
a° --> å
o¨ --> ö
etc
```

Is there such a function?

Comment: I don't think your issue is related to your font, accents are in separate glyphs in your example.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I'm not sure how it works, but in the pdf the glyphs seem to be combined to show one character, such as ä or å. But the answer from Stefan solved it, anyway.

Comment: It could be just clever character positioning, I've seen things of this sort in PDFs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to

```
M-x ucs-normalize-NFC-region RET
```